# How can I bind asp:checkBox to a bit field in the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, webforms

I have th following checkbox:

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="checkInformationMessages" Text="SomeText" />
```

and a corresponding bit field in the data table named `subscription_active`. How can I bind this checkbox value to a `subscription_active` value? Might there exist a specifiec control to that need?

Comment: can you show me what have you tried?

Comment: How are you accessing the database?  If, for example, in your code-behind you are fetching an Entity Framework model (or even a Linq to SQL model) then that `bit` would likely be a `bool` on the model.  At that point you'd set `checkInformationMessages.Checked` to the value of that `bool` property.

Comment: Put more detail in your question how you fetching data from database etc